# Suppress default CRM.alert in hook_postProcess

Tags: drupal, hooks, ajax, ui

Trying to figure out an answer to [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9698/refresh-page-after-closing-modal-opened-by-crm-popup-outside-of-civicrm), have tried to just disable a default CRM.alert using `CRM_Core_Session::setStatus(null, false);`  in hook_postProcess (defined in a drupal module), but alert still pops up (not a problem generally, it pops up in a default style, would like to use  **CRM.status**  instead, which works perfectly even outside of CiviCRM, while CRM.alert doesn't).
Any advice, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear all status messages and prevent them from being shown to the user, you can do:

```
CRM_Core_Session::getStatus(TRUE);
```

Comment: you are my hero, thanks!!  For those, who've been asking for exact code example, here is it:    
  **(new CRM_Core_Session)->getStatus(TRUE);**