# How to get a CiviCRM popup form (eg create new Group / Tag etc) working via a Drupal link

Tags: drupal, contacts, groups, tags

We wanted to let a Drupal user 'create new group' in civicrm without needing to go in to CiviCRM itself.

Clues from [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9698/refresh-page-after-closing-modal-opened-by-crm-popup-outside-of-civicrm) suggested we might be able to do it without using API etc. The suggestion was that

```
 putting <a class="crm-popup" href="/civicrm/group/add?reset=1"> Create a New Group </a> into block body (Full HTML input format)
```

may suffice. It didn't as it seems to require 'something' to initialise civicrm

Answer (score 4):

At this point it looks as if putting

```
civicrm_initialize(); 
$manager = CRM_Core_Resources::singleton();
$manager->addCoreResources();
```

in to a module in hook_init() does the job.